# Google+ Plus API for Insights

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am wanting to get via the Google API the details on the insights for my google+ page. As it stands, I can't seem to find anything on it.

Cheers

Comment: The google+ API doesn't support pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open feature request: [Read insights data from Google+ Dashboard](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=682). Star the issue to get updates.